# Content fetched from API is not displaying on android device

Tags: android, ionic2

Content is not displaying over android device while running well over the browser, after searching i got to know it might be an issue of content security policy, on using meta tag

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *; script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *">
```

this is still not working.
Please suggest.

Comment: Are you getting any error? Please paste here

Comment: No error, this is well running over browser but data is not displayed on device.

Comment: Please check "cordova-plugin-whitelist" plugin is install or not?

Comment: yes this is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I am able to found the solution, Why the API data is not displayed on mobile device while running well with the browser, because the browser and mobile device uses the different file system therefore we need to specify it differently for both cases. Therefore using androi_asset for mobile file system `this.http.get('/android_asset/www/assets/data/subjects.json').map(res => res.json()).subscribe({response=>})` for mobile devices and for displaying on web `this.http.get('/assets/data/subjects.json').map(res => res.json()).subscribe({response=>})`.